# jQuery click binding function in Javascript loop using last parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

This is probably me being silly as per usual... but this is frustrating me.

I have a foreach loop going through a multidimentional array, and for each item I'm adding a marker to a custom leafletjs map. Everything's working fine, except I have a custom click event on the marker (the fact that it's leafletjs should be irrelevant), and it's only ever using the last passed parameter.

Here's the code:

```
var markerArray = [
    ["aspiration", -55.63342652633955, -54.1953125, "aspiration-high-school", [19, 29], [38, 57], [75, 113], [150, 226], [299, 451], [597, 901]],
    ["bird", 12.89745, 69.99818, "bird", [22, 20], [44, 40], [87, 79], [173, 158], [345, 315], [689, 629]],
    ["camera", -22.908054128088575, -29.15421875, "camera", [15, 22], [29, 44], [57, 88], [113, 176], [225, 351], [450, 702]],
    ["chef", -46.6909603909255, 106.193125, "chef", [12, 54], [23, 108], [45, 215], [90, 430], [179, 859], [358, 1718]],
    ["computer", -57.37383096593114, 92.71484375, "computer", [14, 18], [28, 36], [56, 72], [112, 144], [223, 288], [445, 576]],
    ["film", -25.91792293614603, -43.69140625, "film", [13, 19], [25, 38], [49, 75], [98, 149], [196, 298], [392, 595]],
    ["gotthejob", -0.490228926463384, -61.02343749999999, "got-the-job", [40, 10], [80, 19], [160, 38], [320, 75], [639, 150], [1278, 300]],
    ["headmaster", -8.5, -60.57812500000001, "headmaster", [40, 44], [80, 87], [160, 173], [320, 346], [639, 692], [1278, 1383]],
    ["letter", -78.77138592818217, -57.15, "letter", [13, 11], [26, 21], [51, 42], [101, 83], [202, 166], [404, 331]],
    ["newspaper", -67.64766505841037, 92.6578125, "news-paper", [21, 15], [41, 30], [82, 59], [163, 117], [325, 234], [649, 467]],
    ["openday", -69.69785394109224, 24.3578125, "open-day", [15, 17], [29, 34], [57, 67], [113, 133], [226, 266], [452, 531]],
    ["prospectus", -11.885147283424319, -136.39453125, "prospectus", [37, 57], [74, 113], [148, 226], [295, 452], [590, 904], [1180, 1808]],
    ["ruler", -73.92669969306126, 4.94609375, "ruler", [12, 11], [24, 22], [48, 43], [96, 85], [192, 169], [384, 337]],
    ["schoollogo", 9.64906182688142, -108.50859375, "school-logo", [21, 27], [41, 53], [81, 106], [161, 211], [321, 421], [641, 841]],
    ["schoolplay", -3.013667927566642, -159.54921875, "school-play", [18, 43], [36, 86], [71, 172], [142, 344], [283, 687], [566, 1373]],
    ["sun", 14.98818922264095, 20.26953125, "sun", [40, 18], [79, 36], [158, 72], [316, 143], [631, 285], [1262, 570]],
    ["train", -81.93133285369295, -141.99609375, "train", [42, 30], [83, 60], [165, 119], [330, 237], [659, 473], [1317, 946]]
];
var zoom0MarkersArr = new Array();
var zoom1MarkersArr = new Array();
var zoom2MarkersArr = new Array();
var zoom3MarkersArr = new Array();
var zoom4MarkersArr = new Array();
var zoom5MarkersArr = new Array();
for (var arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < markerArray.length; arrayIndex++) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i <= 5) {
        var thisMarkerTypeStr = markerArray[arrayIndex][0];        
        var thisMarkerLat = markerArray[arrayIndex][1];
        var thisMarkerLng = markerArray[arrayIndex][2];
        var thisMarkerImage = markerArray[arrayIndex][3];
        var thisMarkerImageSizeArr = markerArray[arrayIndex][i + 4];
        var thisIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '../images/map/elements/' + i + '/' + thisMarkerImage + '.png',
            iconSize: thisMarkerImageSizeArr,
            className: thisMarkerImage + ' leaflet-zoom-hide'
        });
        var thisMarker = L.marker([thisMarkerLat, thisMarkerLng], {
            icon: thisIcon
        }).on("click", function () { ShowDetails(thisMarkerTypeStr); });
        window['zoom' + i + 'MarkersArr'].push(thisMarker);
        i++;
    }
}
var zoom0Markers = L.layerGroup(zoom0MarkersArr);
var zoom1Markers = L.layerGroup(zoom1MarkersArr);
var zoom2Markers = L.layerGroup(zoom2MarkersArr);
var zoom3Markers = L.layerGroup(zoom3MarkersArr);
var zoom4Markers = L.layerGroup(zoom4MarkersArr);
var zoom5Markers = L.layerGroup(zoom5MarkersArr);
```

The function `ShowDetails` is currently just logging the name of the element clicked, which is always train.

The variable being passed to the `ShowDetails` function, is a locally scoped one, so not sure why it's not working for me.

Any help/obvious suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: handler is executed once event is fired so `thisMarkerTypeStr` is the last value. BTW, looks like `thisMarkerTypeStr` is global

Comment: Hmm.. So actually, without doing this outside of a loop, I'm not going to be able to do this? I do have it working out of a loop, but there's an awful lot more code :-(.  I guess if that's the way it has to be then that's that, was just hoping I could make it a little more elegant.  Thanks for the pointer, I feared that may be the reason.

Comment: you can use a closure in a loop

Comment: Sorry, thought my edit would show up, I did add a comment to the changes.. but yes, I did change the scope of the variables to what is in my code now, I had been playing with the code too much and pasted the wrong version.

Comment: I see now, thank you!  I don't do nearly enough javascript at the moment, I'm sure things like this will become obvious one day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `with` statement if you dislike more classical closure:

```
var thisMarker = L.marker([thisMarkerLat, thisMarkerLng], {
    icon: thisIcon
});
with({
    thisMarkerTypeStr: thisMarkerTypeStr
}) {
    thisMarker.on("click", function () {
        ShowDetails(thisMarkerTypeStr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you again!  That works perfectly. As yet I've not needed to use the with statement, so I'll have to do some looking up. Much appreciated.

Comment: It is important to note that [using the `with` statement is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Not that you can't use it, but you should be aware of the potential issues :)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript `var` variables are function-scoped, instead of block-scoped. That means that your `thisMarkerTypeStr` is the same throughout the whole function. The behavior can be visualized using this classic `setTimeout` example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) }, 100);
}
// 100ms afterwards, the number 5 is printed 5 times
```

A possible workaround, without having to change much code, is to create a closure inside the loop, that captures the variable:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout((function(localI) {
    return function() { console.log(localI) };
  }(i)), 100);
}
```

Another, more (IMHO) syntatically pleasant way, is to create a `maker` function outside of the loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(logMaker(i), 100);
}

function logMaker(i) {
  return function() { console.log(i); }
}
```

Applying the last one to your situation:

```
var thisMarker = L.marker([thisMarkerLat, thisMarkerLng], {
    icon: thisIcon
});

thisMarker.on("click", ShowDetailsMaker(thisMarkerTypeStr));

// ....

function showDetailsMaker(marker) {
    return function() {
        ShowDetails(marker);
    }
}
```